in .NET9 MAUI, how do I set the DataType and BindingContext so I don't get warnings?
I have turned on CompiledBindings in .NET9 MAUI and I'm trying to figure out how to resolve all warnings.  In my code behind I have a BindableProperty called Count:

public partial class CountRound : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty CountProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("Count", typeof(int), typeof(CountRound), 0); 
    public int Count
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(CountProperty);
        set => SetValue(CountProperty, value);
    }
    public CountRound()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

in .NET8 I set the BindingContext for the ContentView and bound the Label Text to Count:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:MyApp.Models"
             x:Class="MyApp.ContentViews.CountRound"
             BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Border x:Name="CountBorder"
        StrokeShape="Ellipse"
        StrokeThickness="2"
        Stroke="{Binding Source={x:Static models:SiteConfiguration.RoundBorderColor}}"
        BackgroundColor="White"
        Opacity=".85"
        HeightRequest="24">
        <Label 
            Text="{Binding Count}"
            FontSize="12"
            TextColor="Black"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
            VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
            Padding="0"/>
    </Border>
</ContentView>

the DataContext for the BindingContext resolved itself to CountRound, the Text of the Label resolved Count properly, and the Border Stroke recognized that it is a Color:



With .NET9  this code results in compliler warnings that DataType should be set on the BindingContext and Border Stroke lines, so I sent the DataType on the ContentView and Border Stroke:
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:JMoApp.Models"
             xmlns:contentViews="clr-namespace:JMoApp.ContentViews"
             x:Class="JMoApp.ContentViews.CountRound"
             x:DataType="contentViews:CountRound"
             BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Border x:Name="CountBorder"
            StrokeShape="Ellipse"
            StrokeThickness="2"
            Stroke="{Binding x:DataType=Color, Source={x:Static models:SiteConfiguration.RoundBorderColor}}"
            BackgroundColor="White"
            Opacity=".85"
            HeightRequest="24">
        <Label 
            Text="{Binding Count}"
            FontSize="12"
            TextColor="Black"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
            VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
            Padding="0"  />
    </Border>
</ContentView>

That resolved the compiler warning on the Border Stroke but NOT the Binding Context, even though it is resolving the DataContext of the BindingContext to the proper type:

So then I moved the DataType declaration to within the BindingContext:

which did clear the compiler warning on that line, but now the Label Text has resolved to the DataType 'BindingExtension' and can no longer resolve property 'Count'

So I added the DataType back to the ContenctView, but this creates a new warning:


Why is BindingContext resolving to BindingExtenstion when I am setting it to CountRound?  Why do I need to set the DataType in the ContentView and the BindingContext?  How/where should the DataType be defined?
